# Prolog Database Rules

Tags: windows, prolog

I have 2 questions about Prolog Programming.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
message(bob,kelly).
message(patrick,ann).
```

The database continues in this format. So my question is in SWI Prolog how can I write a rule and save it while the database is open that will find out if bob sent or received any message?

The other one is to write a rule to see if two people sent or received messages between them I have an idea how to do that but its really confusing using SWI Prolog.

All the help appreciated!

Comment: (1) put the `message` statements into a file, (2) run your prolog environment and include the file, (3) enter a query, such as `message(bob, X).` and you'll see Prolog will give you values of `X` that are indicated in your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've been confused by the Prolog notion of "database." Usually "relational database" is understood to mean RDBMS, which is an acronym for relational database *management system*. Prolog provides you with a relational database, but it isn't in-and-of-itself, a database *management system*.

Prolog doesn't "open a database", it "consults a file." When you do `[foo]`, it just opens `foo.pl`, parses the contents into memory, and closes the file. The file does not remain "open." If you `asserta/1` or `retract/1` on facts that originated in that file, the changes happen in memory, but Prolog doesn't know or care that they came from that file, and Prolog won't ever magically reconsult the file after it is changed or write a new file to disk in its place.

If you want Prolog to know that Bob sent Kelly a message, you're going to have to assert it. If you want the file to remain up-to-date after that, you're going to have to open the file and write the data to it. More importantly, perhaps, you have to understand that if you run multiple Prologs, they're not somehow going to connect to and share a single database. They're both going to operate on their own in-memory store. This means if you do go to the trouble to make your changes persistent, you have to ensure that you only have one process using the file. If you have more than one, they'll stomp on each other's changes.